# Error when attempting to create a blob from a JSON.stringified object

Tags: javascript

I have an object that is stringified successfully, but then there's an error when a blob is attempted to be created from it: "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Blob': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence."  A file with the proper name is then successfully downloaded, but it has no contents.  Might someone know what I'm doing wrong when creating the Blob?  Thanks!

This is the code I'm using for exporting the file:

```
const data = JSON.stringify(arrayObject);
const blob1 = new Blob(data, { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });
const name = this.currentUser.username + ".json";

//Check the Browser.
const isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
if (isIE) { window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob1, name); }
else {
    const url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    const link = url.createObjectURL(blob1);
    var a = $("<a />");
    a.attr("download", name);
    a.attr("href", link);
    $("body").append(a);
    a[0].click();
    $("body").remove(a);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

https://javascript.info/blob describes the constructor syntax as new Blob(blobParts, options), where blobParts is an array of Blob/BufferSource/String values.  The issue is fixed when the first line is changed to the following:

```
const data = [JSON.stringify(arrayObject)];
```

Comment: you answer your own question immediately?

Comment: There's actually a checkbox for answering your own question, I figured it out while writing it, and decided to assist others if they had the same problem, rather than removing it.